# GitLab CI: configure YAML file on java project

Tags: java, gitlab, yaml

I have the MyJava.Java that represents my whole project. In the past, I used to execute MyJava.Java in eclipse and working well, but now I want to make the process much more automated and execute it using the GitLab runner pipeline.

my YAML file is very simple just read the MyJava.Java and execute it.

```
build:
  stage: build
  only:
      - myBranch
  tags:
    - MyBuilder
  image: openjdk:8-jdk
  script: javac MyPath/MyJava.java
```

MyJava has a code and dependency that connected to other files such as this

```
package myfolder.generator;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Provider;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
```

But whenever I execute the file it shows an error of every import/package such as:

```
error: package com.google.inject does not exist - import com.google.inject.Inject;
```

Any hint?

**The result of executing the MyJava.Javewill generates a jar file that contains the data that I want.  I just mentioned this in case you have another way.**

Comment: You don't have any step that downloads your dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a java artifact (jar or war) using a CI/CD pipeline you must configure your project to use a dependency manager such as Maven, Gradle or Ant. After you configure your project you will be able to define a build script on the YML file to compile all the necessary dependencies into a java artifact.

Comment: do you mean configure my existing java project? do you have any examples?

Comment: If you are using any Eclipse flavored IDE you can change your project to Maven by following this guide
https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: how can i build a script for this once I convert my project to maven - also, if I have a plugin.xml, can I use this instead of pom.xml?

Comment: No. If you're going to use Maven you must define a pom.xml with its proper structure in order to build your project with the maven compiler. If you used the Eclipse tool to convert your project it automatically generates the pom.xml file. In your YML file in the script part you must write: mvn clean install to build. You must use a maven docker image for this purpose